# SOAP envelope with header authentication call php

Tags: php, soap

I have to consume a webservice, but can't find a proper way to create the call.
This is the xml the company provide as example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Qpay.POS.Gateway.ServiceContracts" xmlns:urn1="urn:Qpay.POS.Gateway.DataContracts">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <urn:GetProvidersRequest>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <urn:Header>
        <urn1:CertPublicKey>XX-XX-XX-XX-XX</urn1:CertPublicKey>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <urn1:UIID>XX</urn1:UIID>
        <urn1:User>XXXX</urn1:User>
     </urn:Header>
  </urn:GetProvidersRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Tried using this:

```
$soapURL = "https://pos.qpay123.biz/dBar/Gateway.svc?" ;
$soapParameters = Array('UIID' => "63", 'User' => "System") ;
$soapFunction = "GetProvidersRequest" ;

$soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL, $soapParameters);

$soapResult = $soapClient->__soapCall($soapFunction) ;

var_dump($soapResult);
```

But i get a false as var dump, can you point me on the right direction to solve it?

Thanks